# Spark job aborted

Tags: python, apache-spark

I would like to add a prediction column to my dataframe given the logistic regression model. The function is below:

```
def add_probability(df, model):

coefficients_broadcast = sc.broadcast(model.coefficients)
intercept = model.intercept

    def get_p(features):

    # Compute the raw value
        raw_prediction = coefficients_broadcast.value.dot(features)

    # Bound the raw value between 20 and -20
        if raw_prediction>20: raw_prediction=20
        if raw_prediction<-20: raw_prediction=-20
        print raw_prediction

    # Return the probability
        return (1+exp(-raw_prediction))^(-1)

    get_p_udf = udf(get_p, DoubleType())
    return df.withColumn('p', get_p_udf('features'))
```

In the nested function get_p, it calculates the probability for an observation given a list of features.
So, after I define the function, I apply it to my training dataframe.

```
add_probability_model_basic = lambda df: add_probability(df, lr_model_basic)
training_predictions = add_probability_model_basic(ohe_train_df).cache()

print training_predictions.first()
```

However, when I tried to see the first row, the following error comes:

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 98.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 98.0 (TID 270, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last)`

And if I comment out the last print command, it seems that my code generates the `training_predictions` dataframe successfully.I am very frustrated why it cannot print out the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will absolutely love the reason why it fails:

```
return (1+exp(-raw_prediction))^(-1)
```

should be

```
return (1+exp(-raw_prediction))**(-1)
```

Glad I could help